# Como carregar uma variável dentro da mensagem via módulo customizado?

Tags: magento

Estou fazendo um modulo para exibição da quantidade de estoque na pagina do produto apenas se a quantidade for menor que a definida nas opções. beleza, mas a minha dúvida é:
`O estoque está com menos que %s unidades` . Quero saber como faço pra referenciar a variável %s dentro da minha mensagem!?
código usado para construção do **config.xml**

```
    <stockmessages>
        <option>
            <stockmessages_enable>1</stockmessages_enable>
            <stockmessages_min_qty>5</stockmessages_min_qty>
            <stockmessages_message>The stock is below than %s items</stockmessages_message>
        </option>
    </stockmessages>
```

Isso permite que eu carregue uma mensagem padrao, certo, e segue o codigo ao utilizá-la em meu default.phtml:

```
<p class="availability in-stock"><?php $quantity=Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); if($quantity<= Mage::getStoreConfig('stockmessages/option/stockmessages_min_qty')) { echo Mage::getStoreConfig('stockmessages/option/stockmessages_message') . intval($quantity) . " ";} ?></p>
```

A dúvida é como inserir uma variável dentro da mensagem customizada e pegar pela opção para que o valor carregue na mensagem final. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o que você quer é algo assim:

```
<p class="availability in-stock">
    <?php 
        $quantity = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty(); 
        if($quantity <= Mage::getStoreConfig('stockmessages/option/stockmessages_min_qty')) { 
            $frase = Mage::getStoreConfig('stockmessages/option/stockmessages_message') . intval($quantity) . " ";
            echo $this ou Mage:helper('seu modulo')->__($frase . ' %s', $quantity);
        } 
    ?>
</p>
```

Você pode fazer um **else** colocando a mensagem **default**.